# How can i use jQuery to add up sectioned form fields and update when different values are added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

In my form i have sectioned form fields (section 1, 2 etc...) for each form field i add up the values and display the total in the final field of each section, however if a user enters say 5 and then removes it and enters 0, the 5 is still added in the final score and i am unsure of how to allow changes to values so that they get rid of the old value.

The current way is:

```
User adds value 5;
5 += final section field total;
User removes 5, instead puts 0;
final section field total = 5;
```

the code i am using is below

```
var form_inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

$.each(form_inputs, function(i){
    if($(form_inputs[i]).attr("type") == "hidden"){ return false; }
        $(form_inputs[i]).attr("type", "number");
        $(form_inputs[i]).attr("required", "true");
        $(form_inputs[i]).change(function(){
            if(i === 0 || i < 6){

                if(check_valid_pt($(this).uniqueId(), $(this).val())){
                    addValues(attempt, parseInt($(this).val()), i);
                } else {
                    alert("Please only enter 0, 4 or 5");
                    $(this).val("");
                }

            } else if(i > 20 && i < 39){

                if(check_valid_sr($(this).uniqueId(), $(this).val())){
                    addValues(attempt, parseInt($(this).val()), i);
                } else {
                    alert("Please only enter 0 or 5");
                    $(this).val("");
                }

            } else if(i > 59 && i < 78){

                if(check_valid_wfr($(this).uniqueId(), $(this).val(), "")){
                    addValues(attempt, parseInt($(this).val()), i);
                } else {
                    alert("Please only enter 0 or 5");
                    $(this).val("");
                }

            } else if(i > 77 && i < 108){

                if(check_valid_wfr($(this).uniqueId(), "", $(this).val())){
                    addValues(attempt, parseInt($(this).val()), i);
                } else {
                    alert("Please only enter 0, 3 or 5");
                    $(this).val("");
                }

            } else if(i > 128 && i < 159){

                if(check_valid_er($(this).uniqueId(), $(this).val())){
                    addValues(attempt, parseInt($(this).val()), i);
                } else {
                    alert("Please only enter 0, 3 or 5");
                    $(this).val("");
                }

            }
        });
});
```

Comment: it would help f we could see `check_valid_sr(()`, `check_valid_wfr()`, `check_valid_pt()` and `check_valid_er()`, there is probably a better way to do whatever all those functions are doing...

Comment: Though my answer below does solve the problem, it occurs to me that you might be better off creating select boxes instead of the inputs. Just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like the below:

```js
$('.addMe').change(function () {
    $('.addMe').removeClass('hasError');
    var ttl = 0;
    $('.addMe').each(function (i, e) {
        ttl = Number($(e).val()) + ttl;
        var validVals = $(this).data('valid-vals').split(',');
        if (validVals.length > 0 && $(this).val() != '' && $.inArray($(this).val(), validVals) === -1) {
            $(this).addClass('hasError');
            $(this).val(validVals.join(', ') + ' only');
        }
    });
    $('#cost').html($('.hasError').length > 0 ? '' : ttl);
});
$('.addMe').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val().match(/only/i)) {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).removeClass('hasError');
    }
});
```

```css
.addMe {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.hasError {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cost"></div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" value="" class="addMe" data-valid-vals="0,4,5" />Only - 0, 4, 5
<br>
<input type="text" value="" class="addMe" data-valid-vals="0,5" />Only - 0, 5
<br>
<input type="text" value="" class="addMe" data-valid-vals="0,5" />Only - 0, 5
<br>
<input type="text" value="" class="addMe" data-valid-vals="0,3,5" />Only - 0, 3, 5
<br>
<input type="text" value="" class="addMe" data-valid-vals="0,3,5" />Only - 0, 3, 5
<br>
```